# Determine Mapping Function or Approximation from Massive Amount of Data

Tags: algorithm, mapping

Is there a good/well known approach to flushing out a mapping function/approximation having access to lots of mapped data?

#### E.g. Situation

Let's say I have the domain space of a 3D cube (bottom_left: 0,0,0, top_right: 10,10,10). `E.g. points: (0,0,1), (1,2,3)` etc.

Each point maps to a separate series of 3 values in the solution space. We do NOT know the mapping function which is I guess perhaps the heart of the problem. But we do have a massive amount of mapped data. From the data these values were found to range from (-30.0 to +30.0). `E.g. data:`
`[0,0,1] -> (0.1, 0.1, 0.1), [1,2,3]-> (10.2, 3.1, 29.3)` etc.

Any two different keys CAN be mapped to the same point in the solution space however these keys will be positioned far away from one another in the domain space.

We also have the last position and a condition where the searched domain position cannot be a greater distance than a given distance `e.g (0.1,0.1,0.1)` from the last position. I feel like this can be used somehow to eliminate the condition of identical solution space values?

If I have a random point `(2.3,6.5,2.6)` which is in the solution space, how would I find the nearest domain value? Since I have massive amounts of data is there a good approach to flush out a mapping function/approximation?

Comment: Can you be more specific as to what is the solution/map spaces are since it is not clear why **(0,0,1) -> (0.1, 0.1, 0.1)** and **(1,2,3)-> (10.2, 3.1, 29.3)**

Comment: Mine is the same question of @shapiro.yaacov: do you know the mapping function? and more: can any two different keys be mapped into the same point in the solution space?

Comment: Updated. We do NOT know the mapping function which is I guess perhaps the heart of the problem. But we do have a massive amount of mapped data. Any two different keys CAN be mapped to the same point in the solution space

Comment: 1. Do not post duplicate questions, 2. add image of input data plot and supposed wanted output because booth of your questions are so unspecific and vague that is impossible to answer this way we can have a hint what data are you writing about. Add specifics like what mapping you need (1D,2D,3D,ND... What are the parameters,what constraints etc...)  Define massive amount of data (10^36 vectors?) what is the target runtime requirements? what precision you need?